# Clear the $y$ of the following equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can someone help me to clear the inconite $y$ of the following equation.

$$x^2-2x+y^2-2y-2=0$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange it to $y^2-2y+x^2-2x-2=y^2-2y+1-1+x^2-2x-2=(y-1)^2+x^2-2x-3=0$

with this we have $(y-1)^2=-x^2+2x+3\implies y=1\pm\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}$

Comment: Easier to see the integer solutions if you write $y=1\pm\sqrt{(3-x)(1+x)}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$x^2-2x+y^2-2y-2=0$$
$$\iff(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=4$$

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the quadratic equation (in $y$) $y^2-2y+x^2-2x-2=0$.

Comment: Why not add and subtract $1$ and then you have $(y-1)^2$

Comment: @Holo I didn't notice it. Post it as an answer.